# AngularJS Directives ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I must make a website. When you press an `IMG` it adds the template from the directive to another div.

In detail, I have 3 imgs on my website. Hamburger, Cola and Crips. When you press one of them it adds it to the Order List.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
        <title>Food Center</title>
        <script src="scripts/skrypt.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="ladne"><center>Food Center</center></h1>
        <div class="d1"  ng-controller="myCtrl" myDir1>
            <img src="styles/img/cola.gif"></img>
            <img src="styles/img/fryt.gif"></img>
            <img src="styles/img/ham.gif"></img>
            <br>
            <div class="zam" >
                Date of order: {{data | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
                <br>
                Your Order:
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = new Date();
    $scope.hamburger ={
        name: 'Hambureger',
    }
    $scope.frytki = {
        name: 'Frytki',
    }
    $scope.cola = {
        name: 'Coca-Cola',
    }
});

myApp.directive('dir1', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<br>{{hamburger.nazwa}}'
    };
});
```

I really don't understand these directives. Would be nice if you can help me.

Comment: can you do what you want without directives?

Comment: so, provide this sample, and we can help you move it to directive if needed